# How can I prevent to create Use [database] command?

Tags: sql-server

When I create a script of the table in SQL Server (2008), **Use [SampleDataBase] GO** command is also written, How can I stop writing this statement?

*Table Name -> Create script as -> Create To*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tools** -> **Options** -> **SQL Server Object Explorer** -> **Scripting**

In the grid on the right, under *General Scripting Options*, one of the options is `Script USE <Database>` and it defaults to True.